# Khalil's proof of local Lyapunov stability incomplete?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

This is regarding the proof of a central theorem (Theorem 4.1) in Hassan Khalil's seminal [Nonlinear systems](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nonlinear_Systems/t_d1QgAACAAJ?hl=en) book:

**Theorem 4.1:** Let $x = 0$ be an equilibrium point for $\dot{x} = f(x)$ where $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a locally Lipschitz map from a domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $V:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (the Lyapunov function) be a continuously differentiable function such that
$$V(0) = 0 \text{ and } V(x) > 0 \text{ in } D - \{0\}$$
$$\dot{V}(x) \leq 0 \text{ in } D$$
Then, $x=0$ is stable.

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCf2o.png)

My concern is that Khalil defines $\Omega_\beta = \{x \in B_r \mid V(x) \leq \beta\}$ and claims that a trajectory starting from $x(0) \in \Omega_\beta$ stays in $\Omega_\beta$ for all $t \geq 0$ just because $\dot{V}(x) \leq 0 \implies V(x(t)) \leq \beta,\ \forall t\geq 0$. But note that $\Omega_\beta$ is a restriction of the set $\{x \mid V(x) \leq \beta\}$ to $B_r$; $V(x(t)) \leq \beta$ does not rule out the possibility that the trajectory goes outside the ball $B_r$.

I feel like there's an argument about the trajectory not being able to "cross" the boundary $\|x\| = r$ that's required, but Khalil does not make? I can informally see why this must be true since the trajectory cannot lie on the boundary ($V(x) > \beta$ on the boundary), and it must "cross" the boundary if it needs to go from inside $B_r$ to outside.

I thought Khalil's book was pretty rigorous and complete, so I'm really doubting that I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Under the hypothesis of the mentioned theorem, $\beta$ is chosen small enough in order to have that the $\beta$-sublevel set ($\{x\;\vert\; V(x)\leq \beta\}$ is contained in the interior of $B_r$ (and in the proof this is explicitly written). In any case, given any ball, under the hypothesis of that theorem, there is always a level $\beta$ small enough such that this is the case.

Comment: @MatteoDR According to my understanding, nothing prevents the sublevel set $\{x \in D \mid V(x) \leq \beta\}$ from containing points in the exterior of $B_r$; the proof in the footnote only says that the *boundary points* of $B_r$ cannot be in the sublevel set. And $\Omega_\beta$ is defined to be a restriction of the sublevel set to $B_r$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right...but basically the argument is that when you start in a sublevel set of a Lyap function (as defined there), you cannot go out the \emph{connected component} (of the sublevel set) you started in.  Now, knowing that $\Omega_\beta$ (which is, as you said, the restriction of the sublevel set) lies in the interior of the ball, should be enough, no?